# how to set path to a file in ASP C# properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

working on a website here, in ASP and C#.

my problem is, when I try to read a file, it finds the wrong directory. here are the code im using:

```
addtext.Text = new WebClient().DownloadString("readme.htm");
```

error look like this:

Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\readme.htm'.

how do I guide the path to the same as my default.aspx ??

Comment: I have tried "../" and "~/" same results

Comment: Maybe new WebClient().DownloadString(Server.MapPath("./readme.htm")); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) has pretty much everything you might need to know about resolving paths in ASP .Net

Comment: cool. ill look into it, i just started working with websites and ASP ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use app keys for saving the address of the folder which contains your files. You can build a hierarchy for different type of files.

```
<add key="WebResources" value="~/Assets/WebResources/" />
<add key="ImageRoot" value="Images\Web" />
```

and then access them like this and concatenate them with further folder of hierarchy .

```
string WebResources = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebResources"];
string dir = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(WebResources);
```